# Blank screen when updating nvidia drivers - 'Apply Changes' in Software Sources greyed out

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, 22.04, nvidia-geforce

I was using Lubuntu 20.04 (Ubuntu with LXQT) and NVidia drivers (GeForce 940MX card). Last few times I run an upgrade with

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

my screen went blank if nvidia drivers where upgrading. I just waited for some time to ensure the upgrade was completed, and then rebooted my laptop (pressing the shutdown / start button for some seconds).

Yesterday I upgraded the distro to Lubuntu 22.04, and again the screen went black (and I know it involved nvidia drivers because when pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 there was a frozen screen of my last view and it showed the terminal doing something with nvidia drivers). So I breathed in, went on pressing enter or tab - enter from time to time, then rebooted and run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

to finish the upgrading procedure. And now I cannot change nvidia driver in Software Sources (I can choose any other option but the *Apply Changes* button is always greyed out), and I don't know if next time NVidia drivers get upgraded my screen will become blank again.

Any help with this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 16th JULY: here is the output of `inxi -G` command, as requested in the comments:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] driver: nvidia v: 535.54.03
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3
```

I also need to add that I've been using this computer for about 6 years now, and the frozen screen problem happened randomly a few times, a known problem that happens sometimes with certain configurations. But it had never happened to me when upgrading the drivers.

Comment: Strange, I don't have that problem with xfce.(GTX 760) Could you paste the outpunt of `inxi -G` into your question? Thus we know which driver you're using.

Comment: How did you install the nvidia drivers?

Comment: The ouput with the drivers info is now in the question. About the installing of the drivers, I think they installed by themselves with the so (new fresh install from dec' 22) and then I chose the proprietary version in Software Sources - Additional Drivers.

Comment: Have the same problem getting a black screen when upgrading drivers under Ubuntu 23.04/RTX4090. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I realised I had compton enabled. I uninstalled it, let's see what's up.

Answer (score 1):

No solution, but I have a workaround. When new nvidia upgrades come in, follow these steps:

1. Log out of your current LXQT session.
2. Switch to TTY1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
3. Stop your display manager. Depending on your installation this might be `/etc/init.d/lxdm stop` or `sudo service lightdm stop` or similar.
4. Manually do the upgrade with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`
5. Start your display manager. `sudo service lightdm start`.

This works without the video output being disabled. If you want to minimize upgrade time you also can download all needed packages within the session and without actually installing the drivers: `sudo apt full-upgrade -d`. After this finishes, follow the above steps.